# Delete one local user account if another local adminstrator ID exist

Tags: powershell

I have few numbers of server where "tempadmin" and "Administrator" are exist as local admin user. I need to delete "tempadmin" id if "Administrator" is also exist. else "tempadmin" needs to rename as "Administrator". Could anyone help me create one PowerShell script?

```
cls
$strComputer = Get-Content "c:\patch\clientlist.txt"
$password = Read-Host "Enter the password : " -AsSecureString

foreach ($server in $strComputer) {
    Write-Host "Working on server $server"
    if (Test-Connection $server -Quiet) {
        $usertest1 = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='test1'" -ComputerName $server
        if ($usertest1.name -ne 'test1') {
            $user = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='test'" -ComputerName $server
            $result = $user.Rename('test1')
            if ($result.name -eq 'test') {
                $result
                # you may just print a message here
            }
            Write-host "$server -> ID renamed and resetting password...."

            $user1 = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='test1'" -ComputerName $server
            ([adsi]("WinNT://" + $server + "$user1")).SetPassword("$password")
            Write-Host "$server -> Password reset successfully"
          } else {
            Write-Host "$server -> Test1 ID already exist"
          }  
    } else {
        Write-Host "$server -> server is not reachable"
    }
}
```

Here I am user "test" and "test1". I tried the above code and I can successfully rename and reset the password. But I am unable to delete if both ID's are exist.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

foreach ($C in $Computer) {
    if (Test-Connection $C -Quiet) {
        Write-Verbose "$C > Online"

        $Users = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True" -ComputerName $C

        if ($Users.Name -contains 'Administrator') {
            Write-Verbose "User 'Administrator' found"

            if ($Users.Name -contains 'tempadmin') {
                Write-Verbose "Delete user 'tempadmin'"
                $ADSI = [ADSI]"WinNT://$C"
                $ADSI.Delete('User','tempadmin') 
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "User 'Administrator' not found"
            # Here you can rename the 'tempadmin' account or create a new 'Administrator'
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "$C > Offline"   
    }
}
```

It's not complete but I'm sure you get the idea here. It's always better to query a client once and then loop through the collection of objects instead of querying multiple times to check for different objects in each query.

I hope this helps you out or gives you some ideas.

More info can be found on [Boe Pox's excellent blog](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/05/07/local-user-accounts-with-powershell.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for above suggestion....Issue is almost resolved and it is working fine in Windows 2008 and 2008 r2. However, getting error in password reset in Windows 2012 servers. Could you please suggest...

Comment: You're welcome :) For the error message on Win Srv 2012 it's best to ask a new question with the specific error message.